# Scroll Buttons To Appear In Line With Native Browsers Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that consumes 40% width of my page. When the content is greater than 40%, the area is scrollable and the browsers native scrollbar appears.

I have added a couple of buttons, that allows the user to click on next and prev, however, my question is, how can i get the buttons to appear on either side of the browsers scrollbar?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scrollarea margin-bottom section" id="scrollMe">
<table class="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jan</th>
            <th>Feb</th>
            <th>Mar</th>
            <th>Apr</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>Jun</th>
            <th>Jul</th>
            <th>Aug</th>
            <th>Sep</th>
            <th>Oct</th>
            <th>Nov</th>
            <th>Dec</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Official</th>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>54</td>
            <td>70.2</td>
            <td>120</td>
            <td>3.21</td>
            <td>65.2</td>
            <td>354</td>
            <td>2.01</td>
            <td>12.2</td>
            <td>84.2</td>
            <td>24.6</td>
            <td>41</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Rumoured</th>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>68.1</td>
            <td>110</td>
            <td>4.1</td>
            <td>70.0</td>
            <td>280</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>4.2</td>
            <td>94</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>42</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="scroller-btns">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://www.designofsignage.com/application/symbol/hospital/image/600x600/arrow-left.jpg" width="20px"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://www.designofsignage.com/application/symbol/hospital/image/600x600/arrow-right.jpg" width="20px"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">Additional details available soon....</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var $leftClick = $('.scroller-btns .left');
var $rightClick = $('.scroller-btns .right');
var movePixels = 0;

$leftClick.on('click', function (e) {
    $('#scrollMe').scrollLeft(movePixels - 80);
    movePixels = movePixels - 100;
});

$rightClick.on('click', function (e) {
    $('#scrollMe').scrollLeft(movePixels + 80);
    movePixels = movePixels + 100;
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrollarea {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 40%;
}
.section {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.margin-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.my-table {
    padding: 15px;
}
.td {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/2USsT/2/

Comment: What you mean by "buttons to appear on either side of the browsers scrollbar"? Can you explain more understandably?

Comment: @hindmost - In my fiddle you can see a scrollbar. I would like the left image to appear to the left of the scrollbar, and the right image to appear to the right of the scrollbar.

Comment: The only feasible way is to place the table into the middle cell of wrapping table and the buttons - into the two side cells.

Comment: @hindmost - Ok, do you have an example as its quite difficult to picture that.

Comment: is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/AJVfK/

Comment: @EyalBarta - Very close! In Chrome that looks fine, but have a look in FireFox and IE (inc IE8).. Doesnt look correct.

Comment: @EyalBarta - here's my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/AJVfK/2/

Comment: Looking at this fiddle in IE11, the scrolling doesn't work.. in document mode IE8 the whole layout of jsfiddle looks messed up..

Comment: hmm I get access denied error when jsfiddle tries to get jquery in IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` css property to achieve what you need. Just add these following css in your stylesheet.

**CSS**

```
.scroller-btns{position:relative; width:40%;}
.scroller-btns .left{position: absolute; top: -50px; left: 0px;}
.scroller-btns .right{position: absolute; top: -50px; right: 0px;}
```

Here is your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2USsT/6/

And another thing, while your javascript is working, it has a bug. Try clicking forward button several times and then click backward button. You will understand. You need to reset `movePixels` value when they reach the end.

Let me know if this solves your problem. :-)

Comment: good solution and thanks for pointing the error with the buttons :) Any quick way this can be resolved?

Comment: You are absolutely welcome. I have fixed your javascript bug. You can take look at here http://jsfiddle.net/2USsT/9/. Let me know if its working or not. :-)